# Prevent Entity Framework adding ORDER BY when using Include

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We have a query similar to the following:

```
from x in db.Table.Include(x => x.Parent)
                  .Include(x => x.Parent.Relation)
                  .Include(x => x.Relation)
                  .Include(x => x.Children)
where /* some query */
select x
```

The problem is that when adding `.Include(x => x.Children)`, the `ORDER BY` statement that Entity Framework adds to the generated SQL causes the query to take a long time to execute - something like the below:

```
ORDER BY [Project2].[Id1] ASC, [Project2].[Id2] ASC, [Project2].[Id] ASC, [Project2].[C4] ASC
```

Adding orderby to the linq query doesn't help either, it doesn't affect the statement above other than adding an additional column to sort by.

Comment: Maybe the question should be: why does EF add the `ORDER BY`? I think it needs it for splitting the query result in the parts that are used for creating the included types. EF probably expects the database engine to do the ordering more efficiently (through indexes) than CLR code. I'm pretty sure there's no way to get rid of it.

Comment: Agreed with Arnold.
You can try to create an index on Children.
An order by shouldn't slow the query that much actually...

Comment: The problem is that even with a handwritten query, without specifying a column in the query to order by, SQL assumes it should order by the child table's primary key causing a very slow query and the warning `Operator used tempdb to spill data during execution with spill level 1` because it's trying to sort all the rows in the child table.

Comment: If you have performance issues or concerns using ORMs you may want to consider using SP's. That's the only way you'll have the flexibility in performance and optimisation

Comment: Doesn't .include force enumeration? That is my guess, I don't think they are Lazy

Comment: What if you add somewhere `.OrderBy(x => 1);` ?

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa Having the same issue on a query with `.OrderBy(x => x.y)` on EF core. It simpy got append to the order by query. So it looks like `ORDER BY y, id`. The `id` in `ORDER BY` dramatically slow down my query about ~400ms. Currently, I see no workaround than using multiple queries instead of `Include` :(

Comment: what I have learned over my long career is that you should not be using EF, or any other crazy ORM, no matter the project. Consider rewriting everything using Dapper, it's really good.

Comment: @gillesemmanuel for me, if I take an EF query as is, (a simple query with just a lot of includes) it takes... 27 seconds to return 86 rows. If I simply remove the order by clause after emptying the cache, I get the result in less than a second... so yes, it can dramatically slow down the process.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apparently, it's something that EF does internally to ease the creation of resulting objects afterwards. You can't remove the `order by` instruction.

Comment: you can do anything if you want, have time and money.

Comment: Sure, but I assumed OP was not willing to re code entity framework.