# EF Core .Include() ICollection property and implicitly OrderBy?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I use [Entity Framework Core 1.1.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/1.1.0), and [EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 1.1.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/1.1.0) as DataBase provider (added this info from comments). And SQL Server 2014.
I have this models:

```
public class User
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserRole> Roles { get; }
}

public class IdentityUserRole
{
  public int RoleId { get; set; }
  public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

I use this code:

```
IQueryable<User> query = context.Set<User>();
IQueryable<User> query2 = query.Include(u => u.Roles);
```

When I call `query.ToList()` I have one SQL-query:

```
SELECT [u].[Id], [u].[Email], [u].[UserName]
FROM [User] AS [u]
```

And when I call `query2.ToList()` I have two SQL-queries:
**1.**

```
SELECT [u].[Id], [u].[Email], [u].[UserName]
FROM [User] AS [u]
ORDER BY [u].[Id]
```

**2.**

```
SELECT [i].[UserId], [i].[RoleId]
FROM [IdentityUserRole<int>] AS [i]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [User] AS [u]
    WHERE [i].[UserId] = [u].[Id])
ORDER BY [i].[UserId]
```

Why EF add `ORDER BY [u].[Id]` and `ORDER BY [i].[UserId]` in SQL-queries? All works fine without any `ORDER BY` statements.
I have this question because if I call `query2.OrderByDescending(q => q.Id)` I have this invalid SQL:

```
SELECT [u].[Id], [u].[Email], [u].[UserName]
    FROM [User] AS [u]
    ORDER BY [u].[Id] DESC, [u].[Id]
```

And SQL-server returns an Exception:

> A column has been specified more than once in the order by list.

Comment: Which database provider?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen SQL Server 2014, EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Comment: This is not question for SO, but for EF Core issue tracker.

Comment: @IvanStoev is this problem in EF-implementation? Or maybe I don't have a good enough knowledge in EF?

Comment: @Artem EF Core is still in development and has many issues (bugs). There is nothing wrong with what are you doing.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25504754/prevent-entity-framework-adding-order-by-when-using-include