# EF Core with Postgres - Poor performance compared to same query as raw SQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, performance, entity-framework, group-by

I'm trying to diagnose the exact issue with a query that I wrote in C# against a Postgres DB that I've generated a context for in a .NET Core WebAPI project with Scaffold-DbContext.

I'm expecting similar speeds for both queries, but when I use the Postgres ODBC driver or PgAdmin to run a query that gives me the same result set, I'm wondering: Why does the "plain SQL" version perform so much better?

**My query in SQL:**

```
SELECT oolk.salesrep, SUM(oool.openqty) 
FROM public.oolookup oolk 
INNER JOIN public.ooorderlines oool ON oool.orderlinekey = oolk.orderlinekey 
WHERE oolk.salesteam = 'Team1' AND oolk.categorycode = 'Category 8'
GROUP BY oolk.salesrep
```

*Running this query via ODBC and returning the result as JSON via WebAPI (localhost) takes: **2216ms***

**The "same" query in C#:**

```
(from oolk in db.Oolookup
 join oool in db.Ooorderlines on oolk.Orderlinekey equals oool.Orderlinekey
 where oolk.Salesteam == "Team1"
 where oolk.Categorycode == "Category 8"
 group new { oolk, oool } by oolk.Salesrep into g
 select new
 {
     SalesRep = g.Key,
     OpenQty = g.Sum(gr => gr.oool.Openqty)
 }).ToList()
```

*Running this query and returning the result as JSON via WebAPI (localhost) takes: **8353ms***

When I use DB logging in my C# code, this is the query that appears to get sent to my PG database by the query expression.

```
SELECT "oolk0"."pk_oolookup", "oolk0"."categorycode", "oolk0"."customercode", "oolk0"."customerdiv", "oolk0"."customergroup", "oolk0"."forecastgroup", "oolk0"."orderclass", "oolk0"."orderkey", "oolk0"."orderlinekey", "oolk0"."productcode", "oolk0"."saleslocation", "oolk0"."salesrep", "oolk0"."salesteam", "oolk0"."shippinglocation", "oool0"."orderlinekey", "oool0"."openamount", "oool0"."openappliedheadercharges", "oool0"."openitemamount", "oool0"."openlinechargeamount", "oool0"."openqty", "oool0"."openvolume", "oool0"."openweight", "oool0"."totalamount", "oool0"."totalheaderchargeamount", "oool0"."totalitemamount", "oool0"."totalqty", "oool0"."totalvolume", "oool0"."totalweight"
FROM "oolookup" AS "oolk0"
INNER JOIN "ooorderlines" AS "oool0" ON "oolk0"."orderlinekey" = "oool0"."orderlinekey"
WHERE ("oolk0"."salesteam" = 'Team1') AND ("oolk0"."categorycode" = 'Category 8')
ORDER BY "oolk0"."salesrep"
```

I find a few things about this strange.  First of all, I'm never specifying that I want to select so many columns from the database, like I have to do with "Plain SQL".  Yet, here they are.  Secondly, this looks like only half of the "real query".  I can't see any "SQL" that does a summation, so I assume this is happening internally in .NET objects and not on the database.

For indexes, I am building a data warehouse with a star schema.  So my join field/primary key on the ooorderlines table is indexed (single column) and every column on my oolookup table has an index on it (single column).  So I don't suspect an indexing issue at play.  I am chalking this up to my inexperience with query expressions in .NET.

Where is the difference in six seconds coming from?

Comment: Those are the same Queryies, but you have TrackingOn,  Try the same test with TrackingOff, and also I'm assuming you're on a multithreaded environment, you also want to set gcServer=true, I believe this occurs now in the CSProj file

Comment: This is a known issue with current EF Core `GroupBy` translation. See [Roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/wiki/Roadmap) - [GroupBy translation](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/2341). Of course retrieving all the records and doing the summarization in memory is much slower than doing it in database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Curious how you knew that "TrackingOn" was enabled just by reading this post.  Could you be a little more specific?  My Google-Fu is failing me in finding references to "TrackingOn".  I'll try gcServer=true next.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks, that's pretty illuminating.  Do you know off hand if EF6 would yield better results?  I can move away from .NET Core for this project if it means I'm going to get that big of a boost in performance.

Comment: EF6 for sure generates and processes such type of queries much better than current EF Core.

Comment: Are you running SQL from Database or from c#?  Any query of a database requires the results to be wrapped in a interface in the database, then transferred to VS, and then unwrapped in c#.  This will always increase the executions time. Using Linq will always be faster than DB libraries like SQLClient.  The linq is more efficient than the old fashion DB libraries.

Comment: @jdweng I have tested both, and they approximately the same.  So it looks like my overhead from C# isn't that high.  I tested the query in pgAdmin and again in my EF Core project, and finally once again using an ODBCConnection/command in C#.  The ODBCConnection/command and the query in PgAdmin run almost as fast as one another.

Comment: @IvanStoev Are there any huge draws to using EF Core?  We are building a datawarehouse and speed is key.  So it seems like I might want to look harder at the "trusted" solution in EF 6.  I'm not sure if Q1/Q2 for EF Core 2.1 is okay for our timeline.  Thanks a lot for the info, though.

Comment: Wiki has a list of interfaces (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL).  Maybe a c++ wrapper will speed up results.

Comment: Based on my experience with it, EF Core at this stage is only suitable for simple CRUD with queries involving "entities". IMHO.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you!  I've tried the same query again using straight ODBC/"Plain SQL" from my WebAPI project and the performance is stellar.  So I'm either going to stick with that for my application or move to EF6.  The only thing I'm not sure about is if I can keep the WebAPI Project on ASP.NET Core 2.0 and use EF6 in a backend reference, or if everything has to be on one framework.  Pretty new to .NET land.

Answer (score 0):

About added ORDER BY - there is an issue in EF and looks like it won't be solved https://stackoverflow.com/a/26821542/9566462

About unneeded properties in select - you may try something like code below

```cs
var neededDataQ =
    from oolk in db.Oolookup
    join oool in db.Ooorderlines
        on oolk.Orderlinekey equals oool.Orderlinekey
    where
        oolk.Salesteam == "Team1"
        &&
        oolk.Categorycode == "Category 8"
    select new {
        oolk.Salesrep,
        oool.Openqty,
    };

var groupedDataQ =
    from neededData in neededDataQ
    group neededData by neededData.Salesrep into g
    select new
    {
        SalesRep = g.Key,
        OpenQty = g.Sum(gr => gr.Openqty)
    };

var groupedDataList = await groupedDataQ.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```